# data mining in time series data

Tags: r, datetime

I'm newish to R. I have a time-series data frame that recorded throughfall intensity based on a 5-minute interval cumulatively for 15 sensors in two plots. I want to calculate this parameter for every 24 hours (one record per day).
** Because the values are cumulative I want to subtract the last record of each day from the first record of that day for each sensor and then put the results into a new data frame.**

Here is a part of the data frame for one sensor:
TimeStamp_Field,Area,Parameter,Value,Sensor_UID,Depth,Unit
7/1/2017 0:00,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 0:05,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 0:10,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 0:15,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 0:20,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 0:25,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 0:30,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 0:35,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 0:40,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 0:45,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 0:50,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 0:55,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 1:00,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 1:05,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 1:10,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 1:15,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 1:20,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 1:25,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 1:30,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 1:35,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 1:40,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 1:45,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 1:50,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 1:55,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 2:00,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 2:05,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 2:10,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 2:15,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 2:20,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 2:25,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 2:30,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 2:35,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 2:40,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 2:45,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 2:50,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 2:55,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 3:00,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 3:05,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 3:10,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 3:15,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 3:20,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 3:25,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 3:30,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 3:35,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 3:40,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 3:45,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 3:50,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 3:55,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 4:00,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 4:05,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 4:10,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 4:15,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 4:20,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 4:25,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 4:30,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 4:35,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 4:40,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 4:45,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 4:50,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 4:55,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 5:00,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 5:05,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 5:10,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 5:15,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 5:20,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 5:25,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 5:30,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 5:35,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 5:40,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 5:45,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 5:50,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 5:55,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 6:00,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 6:05,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 6:10,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 6:15,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 6:20,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 6:25,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 6:30,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 6:35,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 6:40,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 6:45,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 6:50,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 6:55,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 7:00,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 7:05,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 7:10,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 7:15,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 7:20,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 7:25,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 7:30,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 7:35,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 7:40,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 7:45,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 7:50,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 7:55,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 8:00,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 8:05,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 8:10,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 8:15,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 8:20,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 8:25,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 8:30,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 8:35,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 8:40,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 8:45,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 8:50,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 8:55,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 9:00,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 9:05,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 9:10,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 9:15,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 9:20,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 9:25,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 9:30,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 9:35,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 9:40,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 9:45,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 9:50,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 9:55,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 10:00,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 10:05,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 10:10,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 10:15,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 10:20,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 10:25,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 10:30,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 10:35,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 10:40,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 10:45,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 10:50,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 10:55,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 11:00,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 11:05,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 11:10,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 11:15,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 11:20,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 11:25,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 11:30,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 11:35,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 11:40,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 11:45,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 11:50,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 11:55,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 12:00,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 12:05,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 12:10,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 12:15,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 12:20,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 12:25,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 12:30,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 12:35,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 12:40,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 12:45,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 12:50,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 12:55,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 13:00,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 13:05,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 13:10,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 13:15,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 13:20,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 13:25,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 13:30,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 13:35,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 13:40,S,throughfall_intensity,148.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 13:45,S,throughfall_intensity,148.6,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 13:50,S,throughfall_intensity,148.7,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 13:55,S,throughfall_intensity,148.7,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 14:00,S,throughfall_intensity,148.8,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 14:05,S,throughfall_intensity,148.9,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 14:10,S,throughfall_intensity,148.9,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 14:15,S,throughfall_intensity,149,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 14:20,S,throughfall_intensity,149.1,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 14:25,S,throughfall_intensity,149.1,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 14:30,S,throughfall_intensity,149.1,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 14:35,S,throughfall_intensity,149.2,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 14:40,S,throughfall_intensity,149.2,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 14:45,S,throughfall_intensity,149.2,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 14:50,S,throughfall_intensity,149.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 14:55,S,throughfall_intensity,149.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 15:00,S,throughfall_intensity,149.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 15:05,S,throughfall_intensity,149.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 15:10,S,throughfall_intensity,149.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 15:15,S,throughfall_intensity,149.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 15:20,S,throughfall_intensity,149.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 15:25,S,throughfall_intensity,149.4,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 15:30,S,throughfall_intensity,149.4,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 15:35,S,throughfall_intensity,149.4,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 15:40,S,throughfall_intensity,149.4,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 15:45,S,throughfall_intensity,149.4,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 15:50,S,throughfall_intensity,149.4,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 15:55,S,throughfall_intensity,149.4,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 16:00,S,throughfall_intensity,149.4,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 16:05,S,throughfall_intensity,149.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 16:10,S,throughfall_intensity,149.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 16:15,S,throughfall_intensity,149.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 16:20,S,throughfall_intensity,149.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 16:25,S,throughfall_intensity,149.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 16:30,S,throughfall_intensity,149.6,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 16:35,S,throughfall_intensity,149.6,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 16:40,S,throughfall_intensity,149.6,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 16:45,S,throughfall_intensity,149.6,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 16:50,S,throughfall_intensity,149.6,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 16:55,S,throughfall_intensity,149.7,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 17:00,S,throughfall_intensity,149.7,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 17:05,S,throughfall_intensity,149.7,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 17:10,S,throughfall_intensity,149.7,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 17:15,S,throughfall_intensity,149.7,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 17:20,S,throughfall_intensity,149.8,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 17:25,S,throughfall_intensity,149.8,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 17:30,S,throughfall_intensity,149.9,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 17:35,S,throughfall_intensity,150,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 17:40,S,throughfall_intensity,150.1,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 17:45,S,throughfall_intensity,150.2,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 17:50,S,throughfall_intensity,150.2,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 17:55,S,throughfall_intensity,150.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 18:00,S,throughfall_intensity,150.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 18:05,S,throughfall_intensity,150.4,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 18:10,S,throughfall_intensity,150.4,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 18:15,S,throughfall_intensity,150.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 18:20,S,throughfall_intensity,150.5,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 18:25,S,throughfall_intensity,150.6,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 18:30,S,throughfall_intensity,150.7,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 18:35,S,throughfall_intensity,150.7,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 18:40,S,throughfall_intensity,150.8,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 18:45,S,throughfall_intensity,150.9,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 18:50,S,throughfall_intensity,150.9,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 18:55,S,throughfall_intensity,151,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 19:00,S,throughfall_intensity,151,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 19:05,S,throughfall_intensity,151.2,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 19:10,S,throughfall_intensity,151.6,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 19:15,S,throughfall_intensity,151.8,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 19:20,S,throughfall_intensity,151.9,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 19:25,S,throughfall_intensity,152,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 19:30,S,throughfall_intensity,152.1,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 19:35,S,throughfall_intensity,152.1,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 19:40,S,throughfall_intensity,152.1,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 19:45,S,throughfall_intensity,152.2,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 19:50,S,throughfall_intensity,152.2,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 19:55,S,throughfall_intensity,152.2,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 20:00,S,throughfall_intensity,152.2,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 20:05,S,throughfall_intensity,152.2,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 20:10,S,throughfall_intensity,152.2,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 20:15,S,throughfall_intensity,152.2,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 20:20,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 20:25,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 20:30,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 20:35,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 20:40,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 20:45,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 20:50,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 20:55,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 21:00,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 21:05,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 21:10,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 21:15,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 21:20,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 21:25,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 21:30,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 21:35,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 21:40,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 21:45,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 21:50,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 21:55,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 22:00,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 22:05,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 22:10,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 22:15,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 22:20,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 22:25,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 22:30,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 22:35,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 22:40,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 22:45,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 22:50,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 22:55,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 23:00,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 23:05,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 23:10,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 23:15,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 23:20,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 23:25,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 23:30,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 23:35,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 23:40,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 23:45,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 23:50,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/1/2017 23:55,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min
7/2/2017 0:00,S,throughfall_intensity,152.3,NA1-K03,0,mm/min

Comment: Have you looked at the `dpylr` module's `group_by()`? https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_by.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use dplyr with `group_by` and `summarise`. Just replace the variables in the grouping as you see fit.

```
library(dplyr)

ships %>%
  mutate(TimeStamp_Field=as.POSIXct(TimeStamp_Field),
         date=as.Date(TimeStamp_Field, tz="")) %>%
  group_by(date, Area, Parameter, Sensor_UID) %>%
  summarise(Value=first(Value) - last(Value))

# A tibble: 2 x 5
# Groups:   date, Area, Parameter [2]
  date       Area  Parameter             Sensor_UID Value
  <date>     <chr> <chr>                 <chr>      <dbl>
1 2017-01-07 S     throughfall_intensity NA1-K03     -3.8
2 2017-02-07 S     throughfall_intensity NA1-K03      0
```

---

**Data**:
See question..

Comment: thanks for the response. unfortunately, the results of the suggested way were wrong considering my goal because this data is cumulative and using the average of them is completely incorrect. I want to subtract the last record of each day from the first record of that day for each sensor and then put the results into a new data frame.

Comment: But your data doesn't appear to show cumulative values (even though you say so) as all values for `parameter` are 146.5. In any case, can you update (edit) your question with this new information? I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I've edited my question for 3 days ago. Could some one please answer my question?